# Installing Ubuntu Attemp to mount file system failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install a new fresh Ubuntu 15.04

I was able to do it the first time (before I was on Ubuntu 14.04), but then I wanted to install it again from the ground and start failing.

When I try to install again, I choose erase disk and I get

```
The attemp to mount a file system with ext4 in LVM VG ubuntu-vg LV root at / failed
```

I tryied different solutions, even formatting the disk as NTFS, but I get all the time the same message.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got a solution. Apparently the error is because the logical partitions were locked. I couldn't install as LVM but worked when I didn't check LVM partition.

I did the following steps

1. Start with the live cd and choose the option "Try Ubuntu"
2. Search for the logical partitions

   $ sudo lvscan

This command will list your logical partitions

3. Delete logical partitions

   $ sudo lvremove /dev/ubuntu_vg_example/root/
   $ sudo lvremove /dev/ubuntu_vg_example/swap/

Watch carefully that the folders I put in the commands above are just for example, the directories you have to put there will appear when you scan the logical volumes.

4. After all that shutdown the computer and you should be able to make a fresh installation of ubuntu.